# Why is Xcode pods project saying the supported platform is for Mac when the podfile states iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I've got a pod file like so:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
workspace 'MyWorkspace'
target 'MyTarget' do
various pods
```

When I look at the pods project in the workspace it looks like this:

[image]

If I click on the individual pod targets, each one says the supported platform is iOS, so why does the pod project say the supported platform is macOS? Will it cause problems, should I change it and the base SDK to be iOS?